# Firefox Autofill only works 50% of the time

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, auto-form-fill

There is a drastic difference in the function of Autofill between Chrome and Firefox and I am curious as to why. Firefox only offers to Autofill about half the time (both with address & credit card fields). You can test it out here:

Works in Chrome but not Firefox: 
https://forms.gle/diBsyhX81MqzZiGLA 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_autocomplete

Works in both: 
https://www.roboform.com/filling-test-all-fields